# Add text inside doughnut chart from chart js-2 in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pie-chart, react-chartjs

i want to add a text message inside my doughnut pie chart. To be more specific i want something like this:
[image]

I came across the same issue here in stack overflow by they use chart js in jquery and since i'm new to javascript i got confused. This is how i define my pie chart:

```
<Doughnut
            data={sectorsData}
            width={250}
            height={250}
            options={{
              legend: {
                display: false
              },
              maintainAspectRatio: false,
              responsive: true,
              cutoutPercentage: 60
            }}
          />
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @LucaSpeedStack I've added an example

Comment: @user7334203 Did you managed to display `sectors` in new line ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My example uses the property `text` on the data to specify the inner text:

```
const data = {
  labels: [...],
  datasets: [...],
  text: '23%'
};
```

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Doughnut} from 'react-chartjs-2';

// some of this code is a variation on https://jsfiddle.net/cmyker/u6rr5moq/
var originalDoughnutDraw = Chart.controllers.doughnut.prototype.draw;
Chart.helpers.extend(Chart.controllers.doughnut.prototype, {
  draw: function() {
    originalDoughnutDraw.apply(this, arguments);
    
    var chart = this.chart.chart;
    var ctx = chart.ctx;
    var width = chart.width;
    var height = chart.height;

    var fontSize = (height / 114).toFixed(2);
    ctx.font = fontSize + "em Verdana";
    ctx.textBaseline = "middle";

    var text = chart.config.data.text,
        textX = Math.round((width - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2),
        textY = height / 2;

    ctx.fillText(text, textX, textY);
  }
});

const data = {
 labels: [
  'Red',
  'Green',
  'Yellow'
 ],
 datasets: [{
  data: [300, 50, 100],
  backgroundColor: [
  '#FF6384',
  '#36A2EB',
  '#FFCE56'
  ],
  hoverBackgroundColor: [
  '#FF6384',
  '#36A2EB',
  '#FFCE56'
  ]
 }],
  text: '23%'
};

class DonutWithText extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>React Doughnut with Text Example</h2>
        <Doughnut data={data} />
      </div>
    );
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <DonutWithText />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://gor181.github.io/react-chartjs-2/common.js"></script>
<script src="https://gor181.github.io/react-chartjs-2/bundle.js"></script>

<div id="root">
</div>
```

You'll have to scroll down a bit to see in when running the CodeSnippet due to some weird console error.

It works properly in CodePen though, where I wrote it: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OpdBOq?editors=1010

Comment: Great answer but this is not the exact case. My layout is different

Comment: @K Scandrett Can you explain where did u get Chart  in code ???                                                     
   var originalDoughnutDraw = Chart.controllers.doughnut.prototype.draw; ?

Comment: @Shahnad Chart comes from the react-chartjs-2 library

Comment: @Django Code snippet above works - if you scroll down (and ignore the SO security error). To make Codepen work again (I think they have removed the script references) just add the script references from above into the HTML `<script src="https://gor181.github.io/react-chartjs-2/common.js"></script>
<script src="https://gor181.github.io/react-chartjs-2/bundle.js"></script><div id="root">
</div>`

Comment: When i am trying to use this example. I am getting 'Chart is  not defined'. Any idea?

Comment: @Akanksha sounds like you haven't imported react-chartjs-2.js or maybe importing it sometime after you're referencing it

Comment: how do i change the color of the text in the middle? ctx.color = "#ffffff"; doesn't work

Comment: @phongyewtong  `ctx.fillStyle = "#00f";`