# Overlay text message on top of a chart

Tags: chart.js, react-chartjs

Are there any options to add overlay text messages on top of a chart like attachment image? Or can you give me any references to implement it?

- without message

[image]

- with message

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found the almost same question and answer. It uses doughnut chart.

[Add text inside doughnut chart from chart js-2 in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42759306/add-text-inside-doughnut-chart-from-chart-js-2-in-react?rq=1)

Then I changed it from doughnut chart to line chart. It worked.

https://codepen.io/yzono/pen/ZPoQKg

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Line} from 'react-chartjs-2';

var originalDoughnutDraw = Chart.controllers.line.prototype.draw;
Chart.helpers.extend(Chart.controllers.line.prototype, {
  draw: function() {
    originalDoughnutDraw.apply(this, arguments);

    var chart = this.chart;
    var width = chart.chart.width,
        height = chart.chart.height,
        ctx = chart.chart.ctx;

    var fontSize = (height / 114).toFixed(2);
    ctx.font = fontSize + "em sans-serif";
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.textBaseline = "middle";

    var text = chart.config.data.text,
        textX = Math.round((width - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2),
        textY = height / 2;

    ctx.fillText(text, textX, textY);
  }
});

const data = {
      labels: [
        "10/04/2018",
        "10/05/2018",
        "10/06/2018",
        "10/07/2018",
        "10/08/2018",
        "10/09/2018",
        "10/10/2018",
        "10/11/2018",
        "10/12/2018",
        "10/13/2018"
      ],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "Temperature",
          data: [22, 19, 27, 23, 22, 24, 17, 25, 23, 24],
          fill: true,
          borderColor: "#ffebee",
          backgroundColor: "#ffebee"
        }
      ],
      text: "$3,881.38"
};

class DonutWithText extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>aReact Doughnut with Text Example</h2>
        <Line data={data} />
      </div>
    );
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <DonutWithText />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```